# About embed midi files on a webpage

Tags: html, ios, midi

I am working on a project related to vintage web designs. I would like to embed and autoplay a midi file but:

1. It doesen't work on IOS (I tried with my ipad)
2. On Firefox, sometimes the tune is not played, I don't know why.

Does the midi player depends on the browser or a plugin?
Can I find a univeral alternative to play my tune?

I am using the `<embed>` tag this way:

```
<embed src="tune.mid" hidden="true" autostart="true" autoplay="true">
```

Comment: There are plenty of reasons why you may want a MIDI file on a page.  Considering that everything can play them, it saddens me that it won't work in an HTML5 element on most browsers.  Also... `vintage web design`, what?  I've got a copy of IE 3.0 (16-bit) lying around that will play your MIDI file just fine.  :-D

Comment: This project sounds awesome and I have been looking for a similar solution to the same problem. @rooofl, can I see what come of this project?

Comment: See my solution here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/145528/7452 which describes how a midi (`.mid`) is not even an audio file - and why a browser might have difficulty playing it.  (VLC doesn't even play them)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've referenced this question before and fell upon the answer of using the library [midijs](http://www.midijs.net). 
However, since that lib now has a bitcoin miner included, I've made a variant without the mining code:

https://kitchwww.github.io/midi/midi.js

It can be included and used in exactly the same way:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://kitchwww.github.io/midi/midi.js'></script>
<a href="#" onClick="function(){
MIDIjs.initAll();
MIDIjs.play('path/to/yoursong.midi');}">Play My Song</a>
```

EDIT: updated to include an init function to be called on a User Gesture, as all audio must now be initiated from one.

Comment: I haven't parsed out if it's still actually still called, but just in case, shouldn't that `t("https://coinhive.com/lib/coinhive.min.js", D)` that's still present in your version be stripped?

Comment: UPDATE: due to the [Chrome](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=807017) update forcing user interaction before playing, I've updated the library to now include an `initAll` function which should be called before playing:
`MIDIjs.initAll();
MIDIjs.play('path/to/yoursong.midi');`

Comment: As an update to my previous comment, I see you've also now removed the previously mentioned `t("https://coinhive.com/lib/coinhive.min.js", D)` includer that was [remaining](https://web.archive.org/web/20180831012852/https://kitchwww.github.io/midi/midi.js) in it, although you had already stripped out the [pre-fork code](https://web.archive.org/web/20171216155522/http://www.midijs.net/lib/midi.js) `CoinHive.Anonymous(e);` at the time of my previous comment. The original midijs author appears to have removed the CoinHive code too, now, as he pledged in a comment below.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the *embed* tag is reserved for plugins, which Mobile Safari doesn't support.

Take a look at [*HTML5 audio*](http://html5doctor.com/native-audio-in-the-browser/) tag, which is supported by most browsers.

But please don't play music on a webpage... it's annoying - most either listens to music, have the speakers turned off, or are at the office.

Comment: This is for an art purpose consequently I don't care (for this project) about the good manners, I *want* to annoy visitors and I think they will not visit my website at work.

Comment: HTML audio tag could be fine, but I need to turn my .mid into the standards mp3, ogg... and it is imortant for me to use a .mid - but I can understand that it is not possible.

Answer (score 2):

Your HTML is OK. The problem is that some lower class browsers have lost the ability to play midi files. They have to install an add on. Real Player used to be a good solution, but now they are pushing a cloud subscription. There are plenty of other midi players around, but the users have to install one.

Answer (score 1):

Browsers dropped support for playing MIDI files natively over time. You might want to try MIDI.js, a JavaScript based cross browser library.

Add the MIDI.js script to your webpage:

```
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.midijs.net/lib/midi.js'></script>
```

And then add a link to start playing:

```
    <a href="#" onClick="MIDIjs.play('path/to/yoursong.midi');">Play My Song</a>
```

Take a look at http://www.midijs.net for details.

Comment: Now this player injects a bitcoin miner into the page source :|

Comment: Confirming - bitcoin miner is present on this library.

Comment: New state of affairs: The miner has been removed and it will stay that way. Promised.

Answer (score 0):

For mid, and kar files, I suggest using vanBasco midi player as your default player. See the source on http://midkar.com/blues/blues_01.html

To Embed;
embed src="musicfile.mid" width=144 height=60 autostart=true repeat=false loop=false
(replace the "musicfile.mid" with the name of your midi file)

Answer (score 0):

https://kitchwww.github.io/midi/midi.js Doesn't work because there is missing notes (From what I researched) 
http://www.midijs.net Still has a bitcoin miner 
The only thing i found that is working for midi files is https://github.com/cifkao/html-midi-player, it has the midi player where you can play midis and it, a bar to set the time and a midi visualizer

Answer (score -1):

Use the HTML5 Audio tag.  But like The guy before me said.... please reconsider music on your page.

```
<audio src="example.midi" preload="auto" autoplay="autoplay"></audio>
```

Comment: The `audio` tag does not support midi. At least not yet.

Answer (score -1):

Well, here it is Aug 13, 2017 and don't you know embedding a bg midi on a web page is still a mystery.

In fact I'm pretty certain it can't even be done anymore (except IE's bgsound src, which still works fine for me).

But as for Firefox and Chrome, the solution provided by jofeu is a great work-around.

I only wish there was a way to embed so the midi just starts playing on page load, without having to click anything. I guess those days are gone.

Comment: This is not a answer .probably a comment