# Convert midi to mp3

Tags: php, midi, midi-instrument

I have got one midi file and i want to play that file on web page, currently i am using midi.js player for playing but it is not working on mobile browsers.

Please guide me how to play that file or else how can i play midi or convert it into mp3

Here is my code

```
  $data = fopen ($midi, 'rb');
 $size= filesize($midi);
 $contents = fread ($data, $size);
 fclose($data);
 $encoded= base64_encode($contents);

 $encode = "'data:audio/midi;base64,".$encoded."=='";
```

and finally passing base64 value to midi.js

Comment: Related: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/10915/automatically-turn-midi-files-into-wav-or-mp3

Answer (score 16):

Guessing you're on a linux machine...
The simplest way is to play it with timidity and pipe the output ffmpeg:

```
timidity song.mid -Ow -o - | ffmpeg -i - -acodec libmp3lame -ab 64k song.mp3
```

Comment: You asked for mp3-conversion right? You have to convert that locally to mp3 if you don't have root/admin-access to the server.
Alternativley you could do it like suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7677366/about-embed-midi-files-on-a-webpage)

Comment: i have used this code for playing midi but not working <audio src="flute.mid" preload="auto" autoplay="autoplay"></audio>

Comment: This is working on the server, as long as you have timidity, ffmpeg plus codecs/lame installed.
You can create a bash (or php) script that run this conversion whenever a midi-file is uploaded to the server.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Linux, use avconv instead of ffmpeg because ffmpeg is being deprecated:

```
timidity input.midi -Ow -o - | avconv -i - -acodec libmp3lame -b 64k output.mp3
```

Or lame:

```
timidity -Ow -o - input.midi | lame - output.mp3
```

---

### Edit

FFmpeg was never "deprecated"

Comment: I think `ffmpeg` was undeprecated.

Comment: @CiroSantilliOurBigBook.com a [discussion of this on Hacker News](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=9948257) ([archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20230616155210/https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=9948257)) points to certain Linux distros and forks stating that `ffmpeg` was  deprecated. The deprecation was never true...

Comment: Although `avconv` and `lame` work, `ffmpeg` is still viable.

Answer (score 2):

**FluidSynth + FFmpeg**

An alternative to timidity:

```
sudo apt install fluidsynth ffmpeg
fluidsynth -a alsa -T raw -F - /usr/share/sounds/sf2/FluidR3_GM.sf2 MIDI_sample.mid |
  ffmpeg -f s32le -i - MIDI_sample.mp3
```

Tested on Ubuntu 20.04, FluidSynth 2.1.1-2, and this MIDI file: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:MIDI_sample.mid

Related: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/10915/automatically-turn-midi-files-into-wav-or-mp3/76955#76955

Comment: How to specify the bit rate of mp3 file?

Comment: @Vinod on ffmpeg side: https://superuser.com/questions/319542/how-to-specify-audio-and-video-bitrate and on fluidsynth there's a `--sample-rate`.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue with MIDI.js not working in a mobile browser. It turned out that I had included the ogg files but was missing the mp3s (for some reason the MIDI.js only provides ogg versions of synth_drum).

Instrument files for all 128 General MIDI sounds can be found at https://github.com/gleitz/midi-js-soundfonts.

Answer (score 1):

First install the Timidity package, In Ubuntu just run:

```
sudo apt-get install -y timidity
```

Then run this command:

```
timidity input.mid -Ow -o out.mp3
```

You can change the format to `WAV` or other formats too.

Comment: Your timidity command creates a WAV not an MP3 file.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
timidity my_midi_file.mid -Ow -o - | lame - -b 64 my_converted_midi.mp3
```

running on ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score -3):

[Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/) is an open-source audio converter.

Comment: Audacity doesn't handle MIDI files.

Comment: i am unable to find any code on audacity...can you help me out

Comment: You would need to import the MIDI and then export it as an mp3 format. You stated you could get away with using an mp3 instead of the MIDI. [Here](http://www.wikihow.com/Make-an-MP3-or-WAV-out-of-a-MIDI-Using-Audacity) is an article that walks you through it step by step.

Comment: but using audacity i have to convert it manually but i want it to be done dynamically on server side as they do http://solmire.com/

Comment: I would suggest you upload the midi and the mp3, then use PHP to determine the User Agent or device type with `get_browser()` or `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`... serve up the proper file based upon compatibility.

Comment: If you want it done on the fly it will use more processor of the server, and cause the page to be slower than determining where to direct the user.