# Convert MIDI file to WAV using fluidsynth on OS X

Tags: macos, wav, midi, fluidsynth

I'm trying to convert a `MIDI` file to a `WAV` file, on OS X.

So far, I have this:

```
fluidsynth -F output_sound soundfont.sf2 note.mid
```

This creates an `output_sound` file, however, that file is not WAV, it seems to be in `sint16` format given that I get this output:

```
~ $ fluidsynth -O help
FluidSynth version 1.1.6
Copyright (C) 2000-2012 Peter Hanappe and others.
Distributed under the LGPL license.
SoundFont(R) is a registered trademark of E-mu Systems, Inc.

-O options (audio file format):
   's16'
```

Is there an easy way to convert the `output_sound` to a `WAV` file in Terminal (or in any scriptable fashion)?

Comment: With [SoX](http://sox.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: @CL.: thanks, it worked. Posted the exact command in an answer in case someone finds it useful

Comment: how ? I searched the SOX website for "midi" and came up with 0 hits

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16295459/convert-midi-to-mp3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to CL.'s comment I came up with this:

```
sox -t raw -r 44100 -e signed -b 16 -c 1 raw_audio audio.wav
```

Comment: I needed to set -c 2, also I added --norm.

Comment: wheres the MIDI file ?

Comment: this does not work with MIDI files. You have to run the fluidsynth command first.

Answer (score 9):

There is a simpler way than using SoX: when FluidSynth is installed with libsndfile support, it outputs WAV by default. This is how Homebrew installs FluidSynth by default:

```
$ brew install fluid-synth
...
$ fluidsynth -T help
FluidSynth runtime version 2.0.8
Copyright (C) 2000-2019 Peter Hanappe and others.
Distributed under the LGPL license.
SoundFont(R) is a registered trademark of E-mu Systems, Inc.

-T options (audio file type):
   'aiff','au','auto','avr','caf','flac','htk','iff','mat','mpc','oga','paf','pvf','raw','rf64','sd2','sds','sf','voc','w64','wav','wve','xi'

auto: Determine type from file name extension, defaults to "wav"
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Though, I had to reinstall fluid-synth to get it working

Comment: I think currently the flag/option `--with-libsndfile` is included by default now. Flags/options [are deprecated](https://www.pakstech.com/blog/homebrew-options-removed/).

Answer (score 7):

I found the easiest solution to be timidity:

```
timidity input.mid -Ow -o out.wav
```

If you use homebrew it's also trivial to install:

```
brew install timidity
```

Comment: This worked for me ;) I had tried fluidsynth, but it could not successfully convert midi files that I created using the [python-midi](https://github.com/vishnubob/python-midi)...