# How to change the bit rate of audio while converting from midi file to mp3 using ffmpeg/fluidsynth

Tags: ffmpeg, mp3, midi, bitrate, fluidsynth

I am trying to convert midi file to mp3 using fluidsynth and ffmpeg  on Windows 10 OS.

```
fluidsynth -a alsa -T raw -F - "FluidR3Mono_GM.sf3" simple.mid |  ffmpeg -ab 192k -f s32le -i  simple.mp3
```

The audio bit rate specification : -ab 192k or -b:a 192k are creating an error:

```
You are applying an input option to an output file or viceversa.
```

Is there an option to specify bit rate in the above command.

Taken from [Convert midi to mp3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16295459/convert-midi-to-mp3/65207296#65207296)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option placement matters with `ffmpeg`. You're attempting to apply an output option to the input.

```
ffmpeg [input options] input [output options] output
```

Corrected command:

```
fluidsynth -T raw -F - sound_font_file.sf3 input.mid | ffmpeg -y -f s32le -i - -b:a 192k output.mp3
```

Fore more info about MP3 encoding with `ffmpeg` see [FFmpeg Wiki: MP3](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/MP3).

Comment: The command really works. The volume is low. How to increase volume.

Comment: @Vinod Refer to `fluidsynth --help`. See `-g`/`--gain` option.

Answer (score 1):

Use timidity and ffmpeg

```
sudo apt-get install timidity

sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
```

If I have the file honorthyfather.mid you can choice

**For midi to mp3**

```
timidity honorthyfather.mid -Ow -o - | ffmpeg -i - -acodec libmp3lame -ab 320k honorthyfather.mp3
```

**For more quality use WAV**

```
timidity honorthyfather.mid -Ow -o - | ffmpeg -i - -acodec pcm_s16le honorthyfather.wav
```

**For quality same WAV but low size use FLAC**

```
timidity honorthyfather.mid -Ow -o - | ffmpeg -i - -acodec flac honorthyfather.flac
```

Comment: Working on a Windows 10 system. Timdity is not working in my W10.