# Converting a MIDI file to MP3 in Java

Tags: java, wav, midi, javax.sound.midi

I have midi files I want to convert to an mp3 file programmatically with a custom soundbank.

As far as I can see the whole javax.sound package is only concerned with playback and the Soundbank loading classes are no longer part of the public interface.

Am I overlooking something in the official javax.sound package? Or is there a better way to convert a midi file to an mp3 file using a custom soundbank?

Comment: You could install `timidity` and `ffmpeg`, and call them as processes within Java. Command usage: [Convert midi to mp3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16295459/convert-midi-to-mp3)

Comment: Thank you for your soltution! I am asking this question, because it would be weird if you cannot do something in Java anymore, that you could do 15 years ago and there was no replacement.

Comment: My software JJazzLab has an "Export to audio" feature which does exactly that, using FluidSynth shared library from Java, code is on GitHub: https://github.com/jjazzboss/JJazzLab